# How to validate the size of @RequestParam of type List

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-web, spring-validator

I'm creating a Spring-Boot microservice REST API that expects `@RequestParam` of type `List<String>`. How can I validate that the list contains a minimum and a maximum amount of values?

So far I've tried using `@Size(min=1, max=2)` which is supposed to support collections as well (`javax.validation.constraints.Size`).

I also tried adding `@Valid` and a `BindingResult` parameter along with the `@Size` annotation without success.

I'd prefer using a solution similar to the first example using `@Size(min=1, max=2)` which is more compact and neat. This is for Spring-Boot 2.1.2.RELEASE.

```
@RestController
public class MyApi {

    @GetMapping(value = "/myApi", produces = { APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<List<MyObject>> getSomething(@Valid @RequestParam(value = "programEndTime", required = false) @Size(min = 1, max = 2) List<String> programEndTime, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        } else {
            System.out.println("OK");
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the `System.out.println("Error")` line to be reached but it's actually skipped.

Comment: Your constraints are a logical error, `@RequestParam(required=false)` and `@Size(min=1)` don't make sense together.

Comment: Sure it can make sense. On one hand this is not a mandatory parameter but on the other hand, if supplied, it should respect the size constraint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using method argument validation, you should annotate your controller with `@Validated`, as mentioned by [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring-method):

> To be eligible for Spring-driven method validation, all target classes need to be annotated with Spring’s `@Validated` annotation. (Optionally, you can also declare the validation groups to use.) See the `MethodValidationPostProcessor` javadoc for setup details with the Hibernate Validator and Bean Validation 1.1 providers.

That means you should change your code to:

```
@Validated // Add this
@RestController
public class MyApi {
    // ...
}
```

After that, it will throw a `ContraintViolationException` if the validation doesn't match.

Be aware though, since you only have a `@Size()` annotation, if you don't provide a `programEndTime`, the collection will be `null` and that will be valid as well. If you don't want this, you should add a `@NotNull` annotation as well, or remove the `required = false` value from `@RequestParam`.

You can't use the `BindingResult` though to retrieve the errors, as that only works for model attributes or request bodies. What you can do, is define an exception handler for `ConstraintViolationException`:

```
@ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
public void handleConstraint(ConstraintViolationException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I'm afraid it still doesn't work. I added the "Validated" annotation on the class as suggested. Is it required to define the MethodValidationPostProcessor bean somewhere? Or maybe I'm missing something else?

Comment: @Nel No, this should work. The `MethodValidationPostProcessor` bean is automatically created by Spring boot. I actually tested this piece of code myself and the validation kicks in as soon as I visit `http://localhost:8080/myApi?programEndTime` or if I visit `http://localhost:8080/myApi?programEndTime=A&programEndTime=B&programEndTime=C`. If it doesn't work for you, please make sure to list your dependencies within your question. Perhaps the beans that are necessary aren't being created due to missing classes on your classpath.

Comment: It didn't work at first because of the MethodValidationPostProcessor bean I added.
After removing it the validation succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

As per Bean Validator 2.0, Hibernate Validator 6.x, you can use constraints directly on parameterized type.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/myApi", produces = { APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public ResponseEntity<List<MyObject>> getSomething(@RequestParam(value = "programEndTime", required = false) List<@Size(min = 1, max = 2) String> programEndTimes)
```

For more information, check out [Container element constraints](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#container-element-constraints).